# Shell script to SFTP file to remote server

Tags: bash, shell, sftp

This is probably a question asked before, but I can't find a good question/answer. I need to write a shell script that will be called by PHP program (exec function) to move all *.pdf files to a remote directory via SFTP. The target directory will be constant. The remote directory will also be constant. The files will only be of *.pdf format.

The script must use SFTP, this is a requirement. It SCP will not work. The SFTP port is also custom, I'll have to work that into the code below. I'm not sure how to write the loop thru the *.pdf files in the directory and then remove them on success. Perhaps a slightly different approach would be better.

```
#! /bin/ksh
TARGET_DIR=<path of target directory>
FILE_NAME_TO_CHECK=<file_name>
REMOTE_USER=<user_name>
REMOTE_PORT=<remote port>
REMOTE_MACHINE=<remote server name>
REMOTE_DIR=<path of remote directory>

cd ${TARGET_DIR}
sftp ${REMOTE_USER}@${REMOTE_MACHINE} -
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use private key authentication to avoid problems with passwords.

```
sftp -oPort=CUSTOMPORT -b BATCHFILE USER@DESTINATION
```

**BATCHFILE** (prepare it before launching the command)

```
lcd LOCAL_PATH
cd REMOTE_TARGET_DIR
put *.pdf
exit
```

Answer (score 0):

You can [automate SFTP file upload using WinSCP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16151814/2089697), if you already know the sequence of commands you would use to do it manually. I've copied the sample script from the answer below:

```
echo option batch abort > ftpcmd.dat
echo option confirm off >> ftpcmd.dat
echo open sftp://ftp_user:password@ftp.MyFTPSite.com -hostkey="server's hostkey" >> ftpcmd.dat
echo put directory_path\%.pdf >> ftpcmd.dat
winscp.com /script=ftpcmd.dat
del ftpcmd.dat
```